# "Ironworking" en castellano (en lugar de "Blacksmithing")

Tags: traducción, vocabulario

Tengo un estudiante que quiere ser ironworker y no blacksmith. Sin embargo, tengo entendido que el español tiene la misma palabra para ironworker y blacksmith (herrero). Todos los recursos que veo en español relacionados con la herrería tienen más que ver con el segundo sentido.

Comment: Si. Una búsqueda rápida lo confirma. Herrero es tanto el que forja, fabrica o construye con hierro. En algunos contextos aparecen armeros (para armaduras) y cerrajeros (para ventanas, puertas).

Comment: Tal vez convenga buscar bajo "forjador" en vez de "herrero".

Answer (score 5):

Por lo que entiendo en inglés el término

> **Blacksmithing** [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blacksmith)

se relaciona con la actividad tradicional  e histórica del modelado y manejo del hierro (y la producción de espadas, cuchillos y objetos de aceros, mediante procesos térmicos específicos como la forja y el templado). Eso es algo que en castellano se corresponde con el concepto clásico de **`herreria`** (como una actividad históricamente responsable de la confección —mayormente artesanal— de estos objetos )

Por otro lado

> **Ironworking** [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironworker#:%7E:text=Historically%20ironworkers%20mainly%20worked%20with,shapes%2C%20and%20tempers%20raw%20iron.)

designa, en un sentido más amplio, la actividad de montado, manipulación, soldado y reparación de estructuras metálicas en varias industrias, como las ramas de construcción de edificios, buques, maquinarias agrícolas, etc, que en castellano le caben a las profesiones y oficios de la actividad **`metalurgica`**.

De allí que el paralelo de estas denominaciones parezca correcto, y **`blacksmith`** se traduzca como ***herrero***; mientras que el oficio de **`ironworker`**  —que tu estudiante pretende— se defina mejor como el de un *trabajador* o ***técnico metalúrgico***

Comment: Just to make matters worse we also have tinsmiths https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinsmith and whitesmith https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitesmith at least  in the UK but the OP is in the US I believe

Answer (score 3):

En el ámbito de la construcción:

- Si construye estructuras de acero, puede ser "[*montador de estructuras metálicas*](https://www.construmatica.com/construpedia/Operario_de_Montaje_de_Perfiles_de_Acero)" u "*operario de montaje de perfiles de acero*".
- Un "[*ferrallista*](https://www.construmatica.com/construpedia/Operario_Ferrallista)" construye la estructura metálica del hormigón armado.

Answer (score 0):

Los conceptos españoles e ingleses para este tipo de actividad difieren un tanto, o en algún caso, se hallan superpuestos. En español no existen apenas diferencias entre Herrero y Forjador y ambas se pueden utilizar indistintamente, aunque en algunos casos se deja el segundo, Forjador, para referirse a trabajos más artísticos, siendo en este sentido el concepto "**Ironworking**" más cercano en español al llamado "**Forjador Artístico**" y a la calificación en este campo de trabajos más especializados y creativos, como "**Forja Artística**".

Un **Blacksmith** en un Herrero en el sentido tradicional que crea objetos de hierro forjado o acero principalmente y a veces se utilizan de otros metales. Los herreros producen objetos como puertas, rejas, barandillas, lámparas, muebles, esculturas, herramientas, implementos agrícolas, artículos decorativos y religiosos, utensilios de cocina y armas.

En Inglaterra hubo una distinción histórica entre el trabajo pesado del herrero  **Blacksmith** y aquellos trabajos más delicados y que también son llevados a cabo por un **Herrero** o **Forjador**. En muchos casos en Inglaterra se sigue hablando de **Blacksmith** también para trabajos correspondientes al golsmith, (gold work, silver work), sin embargo, en España para estas ocupaciones hablamos habitualmente del **Orfebre** y **Orfebrería**, pues generalmente trabajan con metales preciosos oro, plata, piedras preciosas... aunque a veces también se incluyen trabajos y acabados de acero fino.

**Ironwork** (Herraje) no debe confundirse con Ironworks (Fundición o Siderurgia) planta industrial donde se funde el hierro y se elaboran productos pesados ​​de hierro y acero. Este **Ironwork** que mencionas, a diferencia del *Blacksmith tradicional* y del *Orfebre español*, es lo que se ha venido denominando "**Forjador Artístico**", donde el uso de herrajes con fines decorativos se hace común, sin dejar de lado, claro esta, otros trabajos quizás menos vistosos, pero de cierta talla y envergadura.

[image]
*Forja Artística*

El **Forjador** o Herrero, como se ha indicado es un oficio especializado en la realización de los trabajos de fabricación, montaje y ajuste de elementos y piezas metálicas de hierro y acero. Trabajan y curvan barras, varillas, lingotes y chapas de hierro, acero u otro metal con objeto de fabricar o reparar distintas herramientas. Sin embargo, a partir de los movimiento de artes y oficios ( *Arts and Crafts*) de S. XIX y XX, *Modernismo*, *Art Nouveau* y la demanda creciente de personal especializado en las artes decorativas y el trabajo con materiales como el hierro, se comenzó a separar sutilmente al Forjador y al Herrero. Así para aquellos trabajos considerados verdaderas obras de arte o de carácter especializado dentro del encaje arquitectónico realizado con hierro, lleva el apelativo de "artístico" y por tanto, se comenzó a denominar como "**Forja Artística**" y a la persona que lo realiza "**Forjador Artístico**".

[image]